# Android Automation appium - x-path

Tags: android, xpath, appium, android-uiautomator

One Element has 2 class names:

one Class name : android.widget.RelativeLayout ,

index      : 11

And Same Element full view has:

Classname   : android.widget.TextView,

resource-Id : com.raaga.android:id/text_view_lang,

Text        : World Music

index       : 0

What is the best way to find this x-path.

Answer (score 0):

1) `//android.widget.RelativeLayout[@index=11]`

2) depends on what the rest of the field looks like, but:

```
//android.widget/TextView[@resource-id='com.raaga.android:id/text_view_lang' and @Text='World Music' and @index=0]
```

should work, but could be simplified in many ways, i.e.

```
//*[@Text='World Music']
```

or

```
//*[@id='com.raaga.android:id/text_view_lang']
```

among others should also work.